# Trying to install apps directly to SDK with ADB. However, it doesn't detect my galaxy ace. Any advice?

Tags: android, sdk, adb

I already restarted server in the console, and I installed all SDK tools packages.
It just doesn't detect the phone.

It says:

```
C:\Program Files <x86>\Android\plataform tools>adb devices
List of devices attached.    (there's nothing here)
```

Oh, BTW, I'm using Windows 7 64 bit Premiun

UPDATE 1: Installing kies and the usb drivers from samsung. Thanks for the reccommendation
 SuNnY_sYeD

UDATE 2: Finished installing and started running adb console and detected the device. Apparently, it detected SOMETHING at least, because now it says :

0123456789ABCDEF device.

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled?

Comment: Yup its enabled. Also i already tried switching usb ports, but nothing.

Comment: is the driver installed? Check the device manager and confirm that the device is there.

Comment: Im sorry im really new to anything like this. Would you mind to explain me how can i check where is my driver?

Comment: Well step one is downloading the driver for your device which can be found here http://www.samsung.com/sg/support/model/GT-S5830OKAXSO-downloads?isManualDownload=true then see if adb is picking up your device

Comment: ok just installed it. Should i run the lite or normal mode?

Comment: well I am not entirely sure but when you plug your phone in now does your computer recognize it? if you cant tell search for device manager on your computer via the search feature in there see if you can find your phone

Comment: ok imgonna update kies and then ill try it :)

Comment: ok thanks it detected somethiong now. Wasnt my phones name, but i guess it might work

Comment: So installing the driver fixed the problem?

Comment: kind of. Havent tested it yet, but i need to know, it detects my phone as 0123456789 ABCDEF. It seems to detect a device but dunno if it will apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well step one is downloading the driver for your device which can be found here samsung.com/sg/support/model/… then see if adb is picking up your device

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this same issue earlier today with my Nexus 7. I had to download a specific driver for it.  Here is the website that should guide you in the right direction.

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

There is also a special note for Galaxy devices on the site:
Note: If your device is one of the Android Developer Phones (ADP), a Nexus One, or a Nexus S, then you need the Google USB Driver, instead of an OEM driver. The Galaxy Nexus driver, however, is distributed by Samsung (listed as model SCH-I515).

Hopefully this helps.

Edit:
Also, if you are using a Google device on Windows, this page is where you might want to start.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html